# What does "nutrition-free" food mean?

Tags: adjectives

"nutrition-free food" - I saw such expression twice recently - but unfortunately do not understand its meaning. Could you please help?

Comment: Could you please say *where* you saw this expression and if it was on a food label. If the latter, I'd definitely avoid buying that product in the future. Have you tried looking up the word, *nutrition* in a dictionary? The meaning will become clear to you. This is a pure general reference question.

Comment: Could someone please transfer this question to *Seasoned Advice* or somewhere else more appropriate for the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term refers to food that has more sugar, fat, or salt than is generally considered healthy, but is lacking in other nutrients essential for good health, like vitamins, minerals, protein, and fiber.